# Replacement for lemon juice in aioli

Tags: substitutions, sauce

I want to make a garlic aioli as a sauce for a burger, however, I do not have any lemons nor lemon juice on hand. I also don't have any limes. However, I do have white, apple cider, and rice vinegars. Which of these, if any, would make the best substitution for lemon juice in garlic aioli?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note, but "garlic aioli" is a tautology. All aiolis contain garlic.

Comment: In fact, aioli comes from "all-i-oli" in catalan that means literally "garlic and oil", so it's redundant @ViktorMellgren

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any vinegar will work, and is simply going to be a matter of taste.  I  see some recipes online that call for 2 tablespoons per 3 egg yolks.  You can adjust from there.  [Here is one example.](https://omnomally.com/2015/01/28/easy-blender-apple-cider-vinegar-aioli/)